# Finding same values in two dataframes of different length

Tags: python, pandas

I have lists of varying size (AAA, BBB, CBC).  I would like to compare the lists and record which lists have similar values.  For example:

```
AAA   BBB   CBC
---   ---   ---
A01   A01   A01
B02   C03   B02
C03   F06   D04
E05         F06
G07
```

The result I am looking for would look like this

```
A01 = AAA, BBB, CBC
B02 = AAA, CBC
C03 = AAA, BBB, CBC
D04 = CBC
E05 = AAA
F06 = BBB, CBC
G07 = AAA
```

Is there any way to do this without looping through the lists and comparing?  I have tried using "isin" command without success.  Thank you.

Comment: your lists seems sorted, is it an assumption ?

Comment: What does your dataframe look like? Is it a Series of Series? What are the indices and columns?

Comment: The list is not sorted.  The example was made to highlight the problem of different sized columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use the following approach:

```
AAA = ['A01','B02','C03','E05','G07'] 
BBB = ['A01','C03','F06'] 
CBC = ['A01','B02','D04','F06'] 
lists = ['AAA','BBB','CBC'] 
df_out = pd.concat([pd.Series(eval(i)) for i in lists], axis=1, keys=lists) 
df_out.stack().reset_index(name='value').groupby('value')['level_1'].apply(', '.join)
```

Output:

```
value
A01    AAA, BBB, CBC
B02         AAA, CBC
C03         BBB, AAA
D04              CBC
E05              AAA
F06         BBB, CBC
G07              AAA
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you.  this worked like a charm, and is teaching me more about how to use Pandas.  Again Thank you